# Find an obj by position in list

Tags: c#, list, search

I'm trying to write a function where the user should be able to store an obj to a specific spot. An when its found it checks if its available and then insert the obj.

```
public bool AddStorageManual(I3D s, int spot)
{
    // find warehouselocation by position in list
    foreach (WareHouseLocation wareHouseLocation in locations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Count; i++)
        {
            spot = i;
            if(locations[i] == null) 
            {
                bool available = wareHouseLocation.hasAvailableVolumeForObject(s);
                if (available) 
                {
                    wareHouseLocation.storage.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }               
    }
}
```

But i need some help with my code.

Comment: Did not need to loop all over the list  WareHouseLocation wareHouseLocation = locations[spot];

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Do you want to have the first available location? This piece of code have some unknown paths what happens if `available == false` for example? Please explain more about what you want to do

Comment: Yes, i was able to fix the problem. What i wanted to do was that i wanted to find the position 'spot' in my list.

Answer (score -1):

```
public bool AddStorageManual(I3DStorageObject s, int spot)
{
    // find warehouselocation by position in list

    WareHouseLocation wareHouseLocation = locations[spot];
    bool available = wareHouseLocation.hasAvailableVolumeForObject(s);
    if (available) 
    {
        wareHouseLocation.storage.Add(s);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```